# How to prevent multiple users login at the same time in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a snippets of login page php code as shown below which verify the username/password from the **control_panel** table. 
My login application below allows only specific users (present in **control_panel** table) to login.

```
if (isset($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['user_pass']) && $_POST['user_login'] == 1) {

    if ($user_from_db && password_verify($password, $user_from_db->user_pass)) {                            
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM trace_users";
        if($result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql)){
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    if($row['open'] == "true") {
                        echo "user " . $row['user_name'] . " is logged in so you cannot login";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else{
                echo "No records matching your query were found.";
            }
        }

        $_SESSION['pageadmin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $username;
        $open="true";
        $stmt= $connect->prepare("UPDATE trace_users SET open=? WHERE user_name=?");
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $open, $_SESSION['user_name']);
        $stmt->execute();
    } else {
        echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
    }
}
```

Although php allows concurrent login from different users at the same time, what I am trying to achieve is when one user is logged in **(lets say userA)** and if any other user **(lets say userB)** tries to login at the same time then message should be displayed that **userA is logged in so you cannot login**.

I am currently using two tables for the code above.

**1.** One table **control_panel** has all the list of **usernames/passwords** (passwords are in encrypted format).

**2.** The other table **trace_users** (screenshot is shown below) 
keeps the tracks of logged in users. If any user is logged in then the column **open** will show true otherwise it will show false.

[image]

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above so that it allows only one user to login the php application at the same time.

This is what I have tried but I think more need to be done:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM trace_users";
if($result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            if($row['open'] == "true") {
                echo "user " . $row['user_name'] . " is logged in so you cannot login";
                break;
            }
        }
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you detect if the user exits at all i am missing some code there. and yes you can use a flag to show that a user is in, but what if one user diden't look out, so you must also implemented a event that cleans up your login status flag

Comment: If you return one row where `$row['open'] == "true"` that should be all you need. Why do you think more needs to be done?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I tried but this is not working. Its allowing multiple users (userA, userB, userC) to login at the same time.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Hi, let say I am userA (who is currently logged in) and if another user (userB) tries to login at the same time then 
it should userB to login. It should display userA is currently logged in so you cannot login.

Comment: The code you have should do that. I am not seeing how the login is allowed, unless you're not disabling the login form when this occurs.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Unfortunately its not doing it. The login is happening here `if ($user_from_db && password_verify($password, $user_from_db->user_pass))`. If the username and password matches then user is successfully logged in.

Comment: Then you need to modify your logic.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Also I have not posted the complete code. This might help https://3v4l.org/u8bCO

Comment: So you only want to allow a single person to be logged in, am I right on this?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yes, lets say if userA is logged in and if userB tries to login at the same time then it should stop userB to login and the message should be displayed that userA is currently is login so you cannot login.

Comment: If you want to limit one user, then add a `WHERE` clause with a few clauses. First to check if a user is logged in and one with a boolean flag set. If both meet the criteria, `do { something }`. Edit: and possibly `COUNT()` if equal to 1.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I am wondering if you can give me hint in the fiddle here https://3v4l.org/u8bCO

Comment: I'd try something like `SELECT col(s) FROM table WHERE user_name=? AND online='open'`, then check / count if the `online` count is more than 1. If it's more than one, then handle the error for it in an `else{}`. `col(s)` represents "column(s)" you wish to select. Best I can offer :)